# Python non-repeat loop

Tags: python, loops

I would like to link 5 point (A,B,C,D,E) with line.

It is easy to make it with For Loop but there will be repeat linkage (A-B = B-A).

Any one have idea to prevent it happen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
import itertools as it
points = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
for pt1, pt2 in it.combinations(points, 2):
    print '{0}-{1}'.format(pt1, pt2)
```

prints

```
A-B
A-C
A-D
A-E
B-C
B-D
B-E
C-D
C-E
D-E
```

Answer (score 4):

You can modify the inner loop to only iterate over the remaining items:

```
points = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
for i, x in enumerate(points):
    for y in points[i + 1:]:
        print x, y
```